# Deserializing a JSON String to LongListSelector Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I am working on windows phone app and I want to show some grouped JSON list item to longlist selector but I am not able to show anything in `LongListSelector` please help me following code I am using-:

### Code Behind

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public string service_name { get; set; }
    public string uid { get; set; }
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
    public object Mutual_friend { get; set; }
    public object Direct { get; set; }
    public string Miles { get; set; }
}
public class ResultSearch
{
    public string service { get; set; }
    public List<UserInfo> user_info { get; set; }
}
public class RootObjectSearch
{
    public string flag { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<ResultSearch> result { get; set; }
}
```

### XAML

```
<phone:LongListSelector Name="test"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding service}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Height="384"
                        Margin="10,136,0,0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Width="436">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Height="301"
                        Margin="10,10,0,0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Width="436"
                        Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Height="64">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding service }"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Foreground="Red"
                               Margin="10"
                               Width="229"
                               FontSize="24" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Height="64">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding fname }"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Foreground="Red"
                               Margin="10"
                               Width="229"
                               FontSize="24" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Height="64">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding lname }"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Foreground="Red"
                               Margin="10"
                               Width="229"
                               FontSize="24" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Height="64">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Contact }"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Foreground="Red"
                               Margin="10"
                               Width="229"
                               FontSize="24" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are able to download the json as a string.

Once you have that string add Json.NET library via nuGet and then add:

```
 List<UserInfo> userInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserInfo>>(response);
```

where response is the `string` with the json inside.

Ok, now link the `List<UserInfo>` to the `LongListSelector`:

```
longListSelector.ItemSource = userInfo;
```

where longListSelector is the x:name of the `phone:LongListSelector` you have previously created in XAML

Comment: sir Mirko Bellabarba i am getting only public string service { get; set; } value and i want display UserInfo class value with header service  value

Comment: are you deserializing your JSON object in RootObjectSearch?

Moreover I can say for sure that `<phone:LongListSelector Name="test" ItemsSource="{Binding service}"` is wrong. You are actually trying to bind a string to the ItemsSource property. ItemsSource expect something like a `List` or an `ObservableCollection`

Comment: Sir how i can get all the item from UserInfo class

Comment: Have you tried this?

`DataContext="{Binding UserInfo, Mode=OneWay}" Text="{Binding fname}"`

Comment: what's the value of your LongListSelector.ItemsSource property?

Comment: sir i want to show all the value of UserInfo class and ResultSearch class now i am abe to show only  ResultSearch  (service ) only how i can show  UserInfo  class value

Comment: I understood what you want but I'm asking you what's the value of the ItemsSource property.. If you bind service, which is a string, to the ItemsSource property (as I can read on your question) it's wrong imo.

The LongListSelector is trying to find the properties of UserInfo class inside `service` which is a `string`. You have to bind it to user-info maybe.. `<phone:LongListSelector Name="test" ItemsSource="{Binding user-info}"`

Comment: also.. have you specified the datacontext in code behind? `this.datacontext = [YourParentObjectHere];`

Comment: sir i did not pecified the datacontext in code behind

Comment: ok, so.. have you deserialized the json in an object?
If yes, which is the name of the deserialized object, and where is located this object?

Comment: var rootObjectsearch = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectSearch>(e.Result);
test.ItemsSource=rootObjectsearch.result

Comment: try this: `<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding user-info, Mode=OneWay}" Text="{Binding fname}"` instead of `<TextBlock Text="{Binding fname }"`

Comment: also I suggest you to remove `ItemsSource="{Binding service}"` from `<phone:LongListSelector Name="test" ItemsSource="{Binding service}"` in XAML